# Scaling rounded rectangles in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do I stop this from happening when scaling rectangles with rounded corners in Adobe Illustrator?

[image]

Comment: That depends on how the corners are made. Are you using the rounded corners function, or are these manually rounded? You can tell by turning on "Show Corner Widget" from the View menu.

Comment: These were made using the rounded corners function.

Comment: Then @Danielillo has your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

Copy a rectangle with rounded corners, and paste in place, but instead of scaling use *Object > Path > Offset path*

This example was made using Offset Path.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Before scaling, unselect all and double click the **Transform Tool**

At the Transform Tool Panel make sure the **Scale Corners** option is checked

[image: Transform Tool Panel]

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you but I got the same effect after trying this.